# Why I can't run datasets from RDatasets packages on my local machine?

Tags: julia

I am experiencing this error when running RDatasets package:

```
 cannot assign a value to variable Base.sleep from module Main
  
     Stacktrace:
     [1] top-level scope
     @ In[3]:2
     [2] eval
     @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
     [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, 
     filename::String)
     @ Base .\loading.jl:1196
```

Could anyone hint as to the possible cause of this?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi. This error isn't related to RDatasets in particular. It seems like you're using Julia syntax incorrectly, but we'll need to see your code to point out the exact problem. Please post the part of the code that leads to this error (the contents of cell `In[3]`).

Comment: even better, the whole notebook up to the error.... so we can reproduce the error and guide you...